# Dynamically generating the filename for svn status output

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a chef-infra set-up with chef-node as a windows server. The cookbook (recipe) is trying to take the status of the svn working copy folder and write it in a file. The nomenclature of the output file is `CHEFRPT_TESTREPO_ddmmyyyy hh:mm:ss.txt`. However, the following code is failing to generate the desired
filename with date and time dynamically.

Following is the ruby code of the recipe:

```rb
time = Time.now

execute 'stat' do
  cwd 'D:\inetpub\TEST_APP'
  command 'svn status > D:\SVN_CHECKOUT\REPORTS\CHEFRPT_TESTREPO_#{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")}.txt'
end
```

Need some help regarding the variable to be appended at the end of the file to generate the filename with current date and time when it was generated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double quotes `"` instead of your single quotes `'` if you want to to interpolate code within a string with `#{...}`.

As you use single quotes in the `command` argument, this interpolation will not be performed and the string will be used as is (that is, including the `#{time.stftime...}` code in the string.

Your final resource should thus look like this:

```
time = Time.now

execute 'stat' do
  cwd 'D:\inetpub\TEST_APP'
  command "svn status > D:\\SVN_CHECKOUT\\REPORTS\\CHEFRPT_TESTREPO_#{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")}.txt"
end
```

See https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings for details about String literal syntax in Ruby.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it's still not working. Tried this command 'svn status > D:\SVN_CHECKOUT\REPORTS\CHEFRPT_TESTREPO_"#{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")}".txt' and this as well command "svn status > D:\SVN_CHECKOUT\REPORTS\CHEFRPT_TESTREPO_#{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")}.txt" but no luck.

Comment: I have added the final resource as an edit. Note the double-quotes around the interpolated string passed to `command`.

Comment: After applying the changes mentioned by you, am getting the below error while uploading the cookbook:

FATAL: Cookbook file recipes/default.rb has a ruby syntax error

Comment: Oh yeah, because backslashes need to be escaped too. I edited again.

Comment: Really appreciate your patience in answering the query but the issue still persists. The cookbook got uploaded to Chef Server successfully, however, the chef-client run on Chef Node has failed with following error:    Error executing action 'run' on resource 'execute[stat]'   Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed  Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'

Answer (score 0):

This issue is coming up because file/folder names in Windows cannot have the colon (`:`) character. Try manually creating a file though UI or command line. Also see [naming a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) for the list of special characters that render the filename invalid.

Since we are creating a timestamp with `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")`, `execute` block is failing. Changing `%H:%M:%S` to some other accepted character should be enough.

Also, as *@Holger Just* pointed out in his answer, we need to use double quotes to interpolate the value of `time.strftime`.

In the example below I've used hyphen (`-`), i.e. `%H-%M-%S`:

```rb
execute 'stat' do
  cwd 'D:\inetpub\TEST_APP'
  command "svn status > D:\SVN_CHECKOUT\REPORTS\CHEFRPT_TESTREPO_#{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H-%M-%S")}.txt"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The %H-%M-%S did not work. It still gave the same error. However, i tried the other method. Generated the report with a temporary filename and then used cmd command to rename the file with date format. Later on added and committed this file in SVN. A longer route but it worked.